# Why am I getting an error in VS code for the terminal.integrated.shell.windows path?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, settings

I'm getting the following error in visual code:

"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"

The error occurred when I add my js file.  Do I need to change the path? and if so, to what?

Answer (score 0):

try just using

`"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",`

if you are still facing issues, select the default terminal from the command palette like so

[image: default terminal]

[image: select default terminal]

VSCode now detects Git-bash and other terminals automatically so you don't need to specify the path.